# Error: return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to repair hive table using msck repair table command i am geeting below error.

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
```

I already set below property still no use.

```
set hive.msck.repair.batch.size=3000;
set hive.tez.java.opts=-Xmx4g;
set hive.tez.container.size=192400;
```

kindly help me to resolve this error.

Comment: Check hive server logs. There can be several reasons: inconsistent directories/partitions, unsupported direcory names, or wrong permissions. There's also a bug on Hortonworks HDP 2.5 to repair some tables.